# Caching VS Authorization

Tags: angularjs, authentication, caching, authorization

I can't clarify me.

In my web applicaction I have users with differents roles, so I use authorization. In client side I use AngularJS and as you know angular use caching.

In the first moment I don't know about angular caching. So my app has problems with autorizathion because I could: login like admin, go to admin menu (then angular cached menu view), logout like admin and login like user, go to menu and then I could see admin menu because was cached. **Note**: admin menu and user menu are the same view (admin menu extends the functionality).

Then I found out how disable angular caching and I solved this issue.

When I read about the topic I have seen opinions for all tastes. Then I wonder:

- A web app that requires authorization can't be cached?  [check this great article](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/29/asp-net-mvc-tip-40-don-t-cache-pages-that-require-authentication)
- In case to use caching, How I can resolve the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in the comments to the referenced article, you can cache authorized content. When you say, login like admin, logout and login like user, I assume you're not using the same account for that. Because typically caching is not intended to handle cases where roles per user change without clearing caches.

Authorized content (or really per-user content), you'd typically want to cache client side as it would fill up your cache on the server way too quickly.

Content that is the same for all users is perfect to cache on the server.

You can vary what is cached on the server by using the VaryByCustom parameter of the OutputCache attribute. See [this article](http://visitmix.com/writings/using-varybycustom-with-outputcache-in-asp-net-mvc-to-support-caching-for-logged-in-users) for more information.

Comment: I regret the delay, I left this issue aside. Ok, I feel more comfortable knowing that I can use cache. Thx!